# If $f$ is an entire function where every power series expansion has at least one 0 term, show it is a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is entire and that in every power series $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(z-a)^n$ at least one coefficient is $0$. Prove that $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried / where you are getting stuck. You will find that people on this site will be significantly faster to help you if you do that; that way, we know exactly what help you need.

Answer (score 10):

**Hint**: For each complex number $a$, there exists an $n$ for which $c_n(a) = 0$, where $c_n(a)$ is the $n$th coefficient for the expansion at $a$. There are uncountably many complex numbers, but only countably many naturals, so....

Comment: Ah so there exists a $n$ with uncountable number of zeros. Such that $0=c_n(a)=\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}$ for uncountably many $a$. Since each derivative is entire, there are only countable number of zeros. Hence the $n$th derivative is 0, and $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: @user61527:I have one doubt regarding above question.Is it necessary that n is fixed?If n is not fixed then how can we say that $c_n$ is a function of $z$?

Comment: @ASHWINISANKHE Recall from the expansion of power series that $c_n(a)=\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}$